# How to use a single DBContext instance across multiple MVC action calls to implement an "Undo-able" page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, dbcontext

Every action call will create a new Controller instance. How can I use a single Database instance such that just call SaveChanges() on that instance when needed and don't call that if I want to undo all actions?

Comment: how about static variable/context?

Comment: SingleTons are bad ideas for a DBcontext... just store all changes in an object which you pass to the next view in a session variable... then on the final 'commit' then savechanges or don't. http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/03/dont-use-singleton-datacontexts-entity.html

Comment: Session would be perfect for this

Comment: I see that you want to be able to undo all actions. Do you ever only want to undo the last action? Do you want your intermediate actions persisted to the DB? Implementing an undo feature is much more complicated than  the question of using a single Database instance.